# Pull row of data from one place in spreadsheet to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, google-spreadsheets, iwork-numbers

I have a list of names and their assorted properties.

[image: Spreadsheet Data]

I am trying to find a way to quickly move an entire row's worth of data into a different sheet so I can manipulate it.

[image: Moving a Row]

Currently I can accomplish this by copy and pasting the entire row, but this is not elegant nor dynamic (the number in blue does *not* update with this method):

[image: Copy and Paste is not Dynamic]

My ideal solution: A name is typed into the "Name" column. The spreadsheet program pulls the associated row from the "main" sheet into the new sheet.

[image: Autocomplete and autofill row]

I am currently using Numbers.app, but am curious if this is possible in Excel, OpenOffice Calc, Google Docs, or any other spreadsheet program. Thank you.

Comment: What you're looking to do sounds more like database work than spreadsheet.

Comment: You've tagged a lot, so which program are you using? As far as Excel, have you tried VLOOKUP?

Comment: you want updates in the source sheet to stay connected, or a formula in the source sheet to be duplicated in the target sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) "Searches for a value in the first column of a table array and returns a value in the same row from another column in the table array."

Taking your info as posted, I created a table on the first sheet and this on the second sheet;

[image]

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A1:D6,2,FALSE)`

Type the name into A2 and B2 will look up the color value for the name "Dagger" in the first column of the first sheet. You will notice the array `Sheet1!A1:D6` given in the formula, that is your table on the first sheet. The number `2` is the column to get the data from. So to get the size, change the column index to `3` and so on.

If you change the data in the table on the first sheet, the data will update.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Spreadsheets, you can go about this in many ways. I like to use the `FILTER` function. Use the following syntax:

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:A;Sheet1!A2:A=A2)
```

You must (may) start at A2 to skip the headers.